# Telling 'tr' that a-z is not only ASCII

Tags: locale, tr

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\012'
```

is   what I need, but it doesn't include all letters. How can you make this work for languages like French? How can you tell 'tr' that among 'a-z' there should also be an 'à', 'é' and 'ç'?

Comment: If I copy & paste your post here into vim, save the file and then apply your tr incantation above against it I get output with the special characters  'à', 'é' and 'ç' missing.  What is your locale, what are your language settings?

Comment: @tink: English is set as lang.

Comment: Like so? LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US

Comment: `tr -s '[[:blank:][:punct:]]' '\012'`

Comment: @Costas: 123 gets through..

Comment: @QuoraFeans tr -s '[[:blank:][:digit:][:punct:]]' '\012'

Comment: @Costas: $ is non-alpha and gets through. But even then, I want a solution, not a work-around.

Comment: Are you set on using `tr`? An alternative solution might be `sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]\{1,\}/\n/g'`

Comment: @QuoraFeans `[:punct:]` == [-!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\\]_`{|}~]

Comment: @Costas €£? Still, this is a work-around, not a solution.

Comment: @steeldriver works. The question is still valid to understand what's wrong with tr.

Comment: I think maybe `tr` just doesn't really handle multi-byte characters?

Comment: most `tr` don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle:

- Set the locale variable `LC_CTYPE` to the one that describe your desired character set and encoding, e.g. `LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8`.
- Use `[:alpha:]` to stand for all letters, as character ranges are not well-defined in locales that go beyond ASCII (they depend on the implementation and on the application), and `A-Za-z` does not enumerate all letters anyway even in locales where ranges are based on code point numbers (it misses letters that come before `A` or after `Z`, of which French happens to have none but other languages do: `Å` in Swedish, Ž in Czech, …).

Thus,

```
tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '\012'
```

However, many implementations of `tr`, including the one in GNU coreutils, don't support multibyte encodings. For example, the command above works in a Latin-1 encoding but not in UTF-8. You can use sed instead.

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*/_/g'
```